# Examples of the Three V's of Big Data?

Tags: bigdata

What are some examples of the Three V's of Big Data? The three V's stand for: volume, velocity, variety.

**Reference:**
Three V's of Big Data, provided by Norwegian University of Science and Technology.
https://www.ntnu.edu/ime/bigdata/what-is

Comment: Actually, you can be above 10 Vs, check for instance http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173060/what-exactly-is-big-data/173310#173310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Volume:**
Simply stated, big data is to big to work on one computer. This is a relative definition, as what can't work on today's computer will easily work on computers in the future.
 - One Google search uses the computing power of the entire Apollo space mission.
 - Excel used to hold up to 65k rows in a single spreadsheet. Now it holds over a million.

**Velocity:**
Data is coming in extremely fast. Traditional scientific research methods of a few hundred cases could take weeks, months or even years to analyze and publish.
 - Iris flower data set
 - Statistical Programming Language R
 - Twitter Firehose (6,000 tweets per second)

**Variety:**
Big Data that is contained in one specific data type or does not fit well within the format of a relational database. This data often comes in the form of unstructured text.
 - Estimated 80% of all enterprise data is unstructured
 - Open Data(Government)
 - noSql Databases

**Iris Data Set:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set
**Open Data:** https://www.data.gov/open-gov/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is four V's which define Big Data.

An [answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173060/what-exactly-is-big-data/173065#173065) on CrossValidated to a [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173060/what-exactly-is-big-data) explains the four V's.

As @MikeStratton has neatly explained the three V's, I would explain the fourth V, which is **Veracity**.

> Veracity is the uncertainty in data.

Examples can be poor data quality, inadequate data from surveys, etc.
This makes the fitted models highly biased and error-prone.

You might also want to have a look at [this discussion](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19/how-big-is-big-data).

Answer (score 0):

IBM data scientists break big data into four dimensions: volume, variety, velocity and veracity. This infographic explains and gives examples of each.

http://www.ibmbigdatahub.com/infographic/extracting-business-value-4-vs-big-data

And also this one picture beautifully summarizes whole Big Data and above two answers with one example covering all the parameters.
http://www.ibmbigdatahub.com/infographic/four-vs-big-data